# How to compile for Arduino in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, compilation, upload, arduino

I am using Visual Studio to create a small Arduino [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch). I want to upload the sketch to my [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board. How do I compile and upload to the Uno using Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to have an Arduino plugin installed (called [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com)).

Their [getting-started guide](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/arduino-visual-studio-getting-started.aspx) says that the build option will compile and upload the code to the Arduino.

Check this [link](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/VisualMicro) also for help.

Comment: Also, you could do it the more difficult way (instead of installing Visual Micro), by following the instructions in this [link](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/VisualStudio)

Comment: Thanks, yes I forgot to say that I am using visual micro

Answer (score 2):

Bash is right. If you have [Visual Micro](http://www.visualmicro.com) installed then just press <kbd>F5</kbd> or click any of the normal Visual Studio "Start/Start Debugging" menu or tool bar commands.

The little green arrow on the tool bar pointing to the right will also work.